# Combine two lines from different files when the same word is found in those lines

Tags: bash

I'm new with bash, and I want to combine two lines from different files when the same word is found in those lines.

E.g.:

File 1:

```
 organism 1
  1 NC_001350
  4 NC_001403

 organism 2
  1 NC_001461
  1 NC_001499
```

File 2:

```
  NC_001499 » Abelson murine leukemia virus
  NC_001461 » Bovine viral diarrhea virus 1
  NC_001403 » Fujinami sarcoma virus
  NC_001350 » Saimiriine herpesvirus 2 complete genome
  NC_022266 » Simian adenovirus 18
  NC_028107 » Simian adenovirus 19 strain AA153
```

i wanted an output like:

File 3:

```
 organism 1
  1 NC_001350 » Saimiriine herpesvirus 2 complete genome
  4 NC_001403 » Fujinami sarcoma virus

 organism 2
  1 NC_001461 » Bovine viral diarrhea virus 1
  1 NC_001499 » Abelson murine leukemia virus
```

Is there any way to get anything like that output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get something pretty similar to your desired output like this:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = $0; next } 
    { print $1, ($2 in a ? a[$2] : $2) }' file2 file1
```

This reads in each line of `file2` into an array `a`, using the first field as the key. Then for each line in `file1` it prints the first field followed by the matching line in `a` if one is found, else the second field.

If the spacing is important, then it's a little more effort but totally possible.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

We could create a sed-script from the second file and apply it to the first file. It is straight forward, we use the sed s command to construct another sed s command from each line and store in a variable for later usage:

```
 sc=$(sed -rn 's#^\s+(\w+)([^\w]+)(.*)$#s/\1/\1\2\3/g;#g; p;' file2 )
 sed "$sc" file1
```

The first command looks so weird, because we use `#` in the *outer* sed `s` and we use the more common `/` in the *inner* sed `s` command as delimiters.

Do a `echo $sc` to study the *inner* one. It just takes the parts of each line of file2 into different capture groups and then combines the captured strings to a `s/find/replace/g;` with

- find is `\1`
- replace is `\1\2\3`

Answer (score 0):

For a more Bash 4 ish solution:

```
declare -A descriptions

while read line; do
  name=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '»' -f 1 | xargs echo)
  description=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '»' -f 2)
  eval "descriptions['$name']=' »$description'"
done < file2

while read line; do
  name=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
  if [[ -n "$name" && -n "${descriptions[$name]}" ]]; then
    echo "${line}${descriptions[$name]}"
  else
    echo "$line"
  fi
done < file1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to rebuild file2 into a sed-command file.

```
sed 's# \(\w\+\) \(.*\)#s/\1/\1 \2/#' File2
```

You can use process substitution to use the result without storing it in a temp file.

```
sed -f <(sed 's# \(\w\+\) \(.*\)#s/\1/\1 \2/#' File2) File1
```